# ChangeBackground of TableLayout when i click on a button on the same layout

Tags: android-layout, android

i have created a linearlayout having 2 table layouts.in the 1st table i have button .now i want to change the 2dn table layout background when i click on the button.not the whole layout ,only the 2nd tablelayout background will be changed.
please help me with some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()` method you need to add a listener to the button and in that listener you can retrieve the view (table layout) and modify its properties. To find the button and the view you're changing you'll need to specify IDs for them in the XML (assuming you're inflating it from XML). Try something like this (untested) code:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view)
    {
            TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mytablelayout);
            tableLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybackgroundimage);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your assistance .it was really helpful for me.i just want to ask one more thing, i have created an xml file n stored in drawable folder. Now ,if i want to set this xml as if i have to do something different or i can simply call it like"" contact.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Name of the XML file);"

Comment: You sure can. Check out [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) about drawable resources.